# CommonCrypto Library Issue

Tags: objective-c, encryption, md5

I'm trying to do some MD5 encryption in my app. Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (NSString *)MD5String {
const char *cstr = [self UTF8String];
unsigned char result[16];
CC_MD5(cstr, strlen(cstr), result);

return [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3],
        result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
        result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
        ];
}
```

When I try to build the application I get the following error:

> ld: library not found for -lcommonCrypto
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How do I resolve this issue? I think that it has something to do with a Framework but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day of digging I finally found the answer to the question.
Xcode doesn't actually want you to link to the CommonCrypto library. You actually only import it into the viewcontroller that is going to use the library.